# Transferring data from gae datastore to a google docs spreadsheet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-docs

My gae application collects large amounts of numerical data. Instead of having users download it, is it possible to create a google docs spreadsheet and save the outgoing bandwidth?

The idea is to create a google docs spreadsheet with the data which the user can then access and if he downloads the data to his computer, it would not count as bandwidth used by my application.

Answer (score 0):

To call external APIs over Http you, or the library that you use, would need to make URLFetch calls, which [count towards outgoing quota](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch).

So you would only save on outgoing bandwidth cost if all users downloaded the same data, e.g. no per-user generated data. Even then the limits dor Google Docs apply: spreadsheet of max 20Mb in size and max 400k cells.

Also, in case of one shared spreadsheet you would not be able to control access to it. Everyone with the Url would be able to download it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. Do you know if google is planning on creating an internal api to access google docs from gae?

Comment: They actually provide a client lib, but it still uses URLFetch under the hood: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ I wouldn't hold my breath for anything else.

Comment: you can also create a google apps script to fetch data from gae.